# Spring security: Role based access control

Tags: spring-security

I'm trying to add spring security to my web application (from [here](http://slackspace.de/articles/roles-permissions-with-spring-security-3/)) which has to support roles and permissions model. I don't know where is the missing part in my configuration but @PreAuthorize doesn't work and I cannot trace it.
Here is my app context file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.njb.app" />

    <import resource="db.xml" />

    <bean id="jdbcUserService" 
        class="com.nj.app.SpringSecurityDaoImpl">
          <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
          <property name="enableGroups" value="true" />
          <property name="enableAuthorities" value="false" />
          <property name="groupAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery">
               <value>SELECT R.SEC_ROLES, R.SEC_ROLES_ROLE_NAME, RI.SEC_RIGHT_NAME
                FROM SEC_ROLES R 
                JOIN SEC_USER_ROLE UR on R.SEC_ROLES = UR.SEC_ROLE_ID
                JOIN SEC_USERS U on U.SEC_USERS = UR.SEC_USER_ID
                JOIN SEC_ROLE_RIGHT RR ON RR.SEC_ROLE_ID = R.SEC_ROLES
                JOIN SEC_RIGHTS RI ON RI.SEC_RIGHT_ID = RR.SEC_RIGHT_ID
                WHERE U.SEC_USERS_USERNAME=?
            </value>
          </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
      <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
      <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
      <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

spring-security file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <!--<intercept-url pattern="/protected.jsf" access="isAuthenticated()" />-->
    <intercept-url pattern="*/user/*" access="hasRole('LIST_USERSSSSS')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/auth" access="permitAll()" />
</http>

<!-- Use database authentication provider. -->
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="jdbcUserService">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

db xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd" default-autowire="byName">

    <bean id="placeholderConfig"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
    </bean>
        <bean id="loadTimeWeaver" 
       class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.glassfish.GlassFishLoadTimeWeaver" />

          <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
                class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
              <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="PU" />
          </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

  <!-- Transaction manager for JTA  -->
<tx:jta-transaction-manager />
<!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven />

<!-- checks for @Autowired beans -->
<context:annotation-config/>    

<!-- Scan for Repository/Service annotations -->
<context:component-scan base-package="...dao"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="...service"/>
```

and web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/root-context.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Enable Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <!-- Allow login pages with JSF which redirects to security check, therefore we have to add the forward entry here -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
</web-app>
```

Here is how I'm using PreAuthorize annotation

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('LIST_USERSS')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/findAll", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"application/json"})
    @ResponseBody
    public String findAll(HttpServletRequest request) { }
```

and here is the request

```
http://localhost:8080/app/user/findAll.json?
```

Comment: This issue is very extensive. Start debuging your application. See if the DelegatingFilterProxy is initialized correctly. Then if the DelegatingFilterProxy captures comming requests. Then if the DelegatingFilterProxy kicks off internaly the AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter. Then provide a thrown exception or something that will clarify what is really inaction. Turn on logging that might help also.

Answer (score 1):

To get `@PreAuthorize` and similar annotations to work, add in security file:

```xml
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
```

Comment: I added this and it still passes the @PreAuthorize

Comment: @sina How does your PreAuthorize look and how do you use the method?

Comment: I added some detail at the end of question, btw wanna use the groupAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery property with query I have already defined there. @holmis83